# How to find a core dump? Narrowed it down to constructors and function

Tags: c++, vi

I'm getting a core dump error (memory leak) and I'm not sure where it's coming from. I tried to run the program parts at a time and minimized the problem. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Base Header File.

```
#ifndef VEHICLE_H
#define VEHICLE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Vehicle{
        protected:
                char *name;
                static ostream *out ;
        public:
                Vehicle();
                Vehicle(string &n);
                Vehicle (const Vehicle & b);
                ~Vehicle();
                Vehicle& operator =(const Vehicle &b);
                virtual void print(void) = 0;
                virtual void read(void) = 0;

};
```

Base Constructors

```
#include "vehicle.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

ostream * Vehicle :: out = &cout;

Vehicle :: Vehicle(){

        name = new char;
        strcpy(name, "");
}

Vehicle :: Vehicle(string &n){

        int len = n.length()+ 1;
        delete [] name;
        name = new char[len];
        strcpy(name,n.c_str());

}

Vehicle :: Vehicle(const Vehicle & v){

        int len = strlen(v.name)+ 1;
        delete [] name;
        name = new char[len];
        strcpy(name,v.name);

}
Vehicle & Vehicle::operator = (const Vehicle &b){

        if(this == &b){

                return *this;

        }

        int len = strlen(b.name)+ 1;
        delete [] name;
        name = new char[len];
        strcpy(name,b.name);

        return *this;
}

Vehicle:: ~Vehicle(){

        delete [] name;

}
```

Derived Header file

```
#ifndef MOTORVEHICLE_H
#define MOTORVEHICLE_H

#include <cstring>
#include "vehicle.h"

class MotorVehicle: public Vehicle{
        protected:
                string make;
                string model;
                double mpg;
        public:
                MotorVehicle();
                MotorVehicle (const string &n,const string &m = "",const string &md = "", const double &mp = 0.0);

                //accessor functions
                string getName()const;
                string getMake()const;
                string getModel()const;
                double getMpg()const;
                ostream & getOut();

                //mutator functions
                string setName();
                void setMake();
                void setModel();
                void setMpg();
                void setOut(ostream & o);

                //virtual functions
                void print();
                void read();

};

#endif // MOTORVEHICLE_H
```

MotorVehicle Implementation. This is where the error happens.

```
#include "motorVehicle.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

MotorVehicle:: MotorVehicle(): Vehicle(), make(""), model(""), mpg(0.0){
        make = "";
        model = "";
        mpg = 0.0;

}

MotorVehicle :: MotorVehicle(const string &n, const string &m, const string &md, const double &mp){

        int len = n.length()+ 1;
        delete [] name;
        name = new char[len];
        strcpy(name,n.c_str());

        make = m;
        model = md;
        mpg = mp;

}

//accessor functions

string MotorVehicle :: getName()const{

        string temp(name);
        return temp;

}

string MotorVehicle :: getMake()const {

        return make;

}

string MotorVehicle :: getModel()const {

        return model;

}

double MotorVehicle :: getMpg()const {

        return mpg;

}

ostream & MotorVehicle  :: getOut(){

        return *out;
}

//mutator functions
string MotorVehicle :: setName(){
        cerr << "dododd" <<endl;

        string nm1;
        cin >> nm1;

        int len = nm1.length()+ 1;
        delete [] name;
        name = new char[len];
        strcpy(name,nm1.c_str());


}

void MotorVehicle :: setMake(){

        cin >> make;
}

void MotorVehicle :: setModel(){

        cin >> model;

}

void MotorVehicle :: setMpg(){

        cin >> mpg;
}

void MotorVehicle :: setOut(ostream & o){

        out = &o;
}

//virtual function
void MotorVehicle :: print(){

        *out << name << make << model << mpg <<" ";
}

void MotorVehicle :: read(){


        *out << "Please enter name for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setName();

        *out << "Please enter make for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setMake();

        *out << "Please enter model for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setModel();

        *out << "Please enter miles per gallon for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setMpg();


}
```

Truck header

```
#ifndef TRUCK_H
#define TRUCK_H

#include "motorVehicle.h"
class Truck: public MotorVehicle{
        protected:
                double cargoCapacity;
        public:
                Truck();
                Truck (string &n,string &m,string &md, double &mp , double &cp);
                //accessor functions
                double getcargoCapacity()const;

                //mutator functions
                void setcargoCapacity();

                //virtual functions
                void print();
                void read();

};

#endif
```

Truck implementation

```
#include "truck.h"

Truck :: Truck() : MotorVehicle(){

        cargoCapacity = 0.0;
}


Truck :: Truck(string &n, string &m, string &md, double &mp, double &cp ): MotorVehicle (n,m,md,mp){

        cargoCapacity = 0.0;

}


double Truck :: getcargoCapacity()const{

        return cargoCapacity;

}

void Truck :: setcargoCapacity(){

        cin >> cargoCapacity;

}

void Truck :: print(){

        *out << name << make << model << mpg << cargoCapacity << " ";

}

void Truck :: read(){

        *out << "Please enter cargo capacity for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setcargoCapacity();

        *out << "Please enter name for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setName();

        *out << "Please enter make for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setMake();

        *out << "Please enter model for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setModel();

        *out << "Please enter MPG for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setMpg();

}
```

Car header

```
#ifndef CAR_H
#define CAR_H

#include "motorVehicle.h"

class Car: public MotorVehicle{

        private:
                string trim;
        public:
                Car();
                Car (string &n,string &m,string &md,double &mp, string &t);

                //accessor functions
                string getTrim()const;

                //mutator functions
                void setTrim();

                //virtual functions
                void print();
                void read();

};


#endif // CAR_H
```

Car implementation

```
#include "car.h"

Car :: Car (){

        MotorVehicle();

}

Car :: Car(string &n, string &m, string &md, double &mp, string &t) : MotorVehicle (n,m,md,mp){

        trim = "";
}

string Car :: getTrim()const{

        return trim;

}

void Car :: setTrim(){

        cin >> trim;
}

void Car :: print(){

        *out << name << make << model << mpg << trim << " ";

}

void Car :: read (){

        *out << "Please enter trim for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setTrim();

        *out << "Please enter name for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setName();

        *out << "Please enter make for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setMake();
        *out << "Please enter model for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setModel();

        *out << "Please enter MPG for this Vehicle:  " << endl;
        setMpg();



}
```

Main

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <typeinfo>
#include "motorVehicle.h"

// car.h & truck.h included twice to test #ifndef #define ... #endif structure
#include "car.h"
#include "car.h"
#include "truck.h"
#include "truck.h"

typedef vector<MotorVehicle *> vectorOfMotorVehicle;

using namespace std;

// prompt the user for the Vehicle type to create, and get the reply
string prompt(void);

int main() {
   vectorOfMotorVehicle v;         // store dynamically created MotorVehicles
                                   // or objects derived from MotorVehicles
   int           numVehicles = 0;  // denotes how many MotorVehicles we have
   string        reply;            // indicates type of MotorVehicle to build
   bool          error = false;    // set when a user response is in error
   string        outputLocation;   // where the output of print() will go
   ofstream     *out = NULL;
   MotorVehicle *m;

   // uncomment following line to test that Vehicle is an abstract base class
   // Vehicle theVehicle;

   // push a Vehicle into the vector so  first "real" Vehicle is at position 1
   m = new MotorVehicle("None");
   v.push_back(m);

   // chose where the output will go
   cout << "Where would you like the output?  ";
   cin  >> outputLocation;

   if (outputLocation == "stdout") {
      ; // no action to take, because stdout (i.e., cout) is the default
   } else if (outputLocation == "stderr") {
      v[0]->setOut(cerr);
   } else {
      out = new ofstream;
      out->open(outputLocation.c_str());
      if (out->fail()) {
         cerr << "Error:  error writing to " << outputLocation << endl;
         return 1;
      }
      v[0]->setOut(*out);
   }

   // get the type of Vehicle to create
   reply = prompt();

   // loop, reading vehicle descriptions, until a "quit" command is received
   while (reply != "quit") {

      // create the new MotorVehicle object and push it into the vector
      switch (toupper(reply[0])) {
        case 'T' : m = (MotorVehicle *) (new Truck);
                   v.push_back(m);
                   break;
        case 'C' : m = (MotorVehicle *) (new Car);
                   v.push_back(m);
                   break;
        case 'Q' : reply = "quit";
                   continue;
        default  : cerr << "Incorrect response\n\n";
                   error = true;
      }

      // if no error, then we have a new Vehicle to initialize via read()
      if (!error) {
         numVehicles++;
         v[numVehicles]->read();
      }

      // reset error flag, and request a new Vehicle type
      error = false;
      reply = prompt();
   }

   // report on what Vehicles were created to test read() and print()
   for (int i = 0; i <= numVehicles; i++) {
      //*out << "Vehicle " << i << endl;

      // print the Vehicle characteristics (attributes)
      v[i]->print();

      //*out << endl;

      // free the storage for this Vehicle
      delete v[i];
   }

   // if we opened an output file, then close it
   if (out != NULL) {
      out->close();
      delete out;
   }

   return 0;
}

// prompt the user for the Vehicle type to create, and get the reply
string prompt() {
   string reply;    // the user reponse to the prompt

   // prompt for and get user response
   cout << "\nWhich type of vehicle would you like to initialize"
        << "\n--car or truck (or \"quit\" to exit):  ";
   cin  >> reply;

   return reply;
}
```

When the derived classes try to call the setName function, it keeps throwing a core dump. Where is the leak coming from?

Thank you

Comment: `name = '\0';` effectively assigns `0` to that pointer, not it's contents.

Comment: Memory leaks seldom leads to core-dumps by themselves. Instead use a *debugger* to catch the crash in-action, and you will find out *exactly* where it is. You could also use memory-debuggers like [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help you find memory errors (including leaks). I also recommend you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert.

Comment: `char *name;` why, you already know std::string.

Comment: @manni66 it was a requirement.

Comment: @user0042 strcpy(name, ""); I tried this but was uneffective..

Comment: You can directly and explicitly know the reason a crash happened if you look at the core file with something like `gdb <corefile> <executable>`

Comment: @Joe _"but was uneffective"_ Sure, the uninitialized `name` pointer points to an arbitrary address. You need to initialize (allocate) it properly before usage.

Comment: @user0042 I think that's where i'm having trouble the most. How do you allocate a new empty char * without knowing the size? char * name = new char doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @Joe I'd recommend you should use `std::string` instead of `char*` if you plan to write professional production ready c++ code. Eerrrm, wait .... Everywhere else you already do so?

Comment: @user0042 I would, but this was a requirement for this program. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure about validity of *name* assingment at Vehicle's contructur, but it may very well be NULL. This will be a problem at *setName* as you try to delete[] NULL.

So Change

```
Vehicle :: Vehicle(){
    name = '\0';
}
```

to

```
Vehicle :: Vehicle(){
    name = new char[1];
    name[0] = '\0';
}
```

and you should have actual ownership of that memory for deleting. Remember to free allocated memory at desctrutor as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did try allocating the memory in various ways, but it still does a core dump. Would you need main to understand better?

Comment: Judging by the comments in your question, are you sure you tried allocation *exactly* how I provided the code? Because everything else presented so far will most definitely crash, this one shouldn't. Notice it must be initialized as an array. Other obvious issues are that you're missing return at setName and your second contructor doesn't call base class constructor. First one won't crash, latter one would crash already on object initialization (because of delete[]). Please provide the main, or better yet full compilable code that reproduces the issue in case you still need help.

Comment: I did what you said and the memory leak is still there. I added the fully compilable code. Thanks so much for the help.